# Mailchimp API (v1.3): addresses added with listSubscribe() don't appear in dashboard

Tags: api, mailchimp

I'm using Mailchimp's API (v1.3) to add email addresses to a subscriber list on one of our sites. Obviously, I'm using listSubscribe() and everything is working fine, for the most part (read: API call returns true, all of the data I'm sending to Mailchimp gets added/updated correctly).

The problem, however, is that whenever a new address is added, the things that are normally supposed to happen (in particular: email notifications to list manager, addresses showing up in the dashboard list status stream) aren't happening.

I've looked around for quite a bit and haven't found anyone with the same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The default action of listSubscribe to add a subscriber is opt-in. This means that when you submit a listSubscribe the subscribed user will get an email asking to confirm their opt-in.

If the user does not follow the link in the email then they will not appear in the dashboard.

You can bypass this by using:

```
'double_optin' => FALSE,
```

http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/listsubscribe.func.php

However this is only recommended for very occasional circumstances (essentially where you are handling the opt-in).

In my case I am not activating a user account until they verify their email address. If let the opt-in email be sent then the user is going to get a number of emails from my web app. I'm being very careful to make sure that they're verifying their subscription and all subscription stuff is being processed by the web app (eg a user unsubscribes within the web app, not via MailChimp).

Answer (score 2):

I talked to the Mailchimp support, and they said those actions won't happen using their public API; there is no way to trigger them.