# Mailchimp API listsubscribe() doesn't add subscriber to my list

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, mailchimp

I am implementing the `Mailchimp API` to my Coldfusion Project. I have performed all the steps that are required to add email to list.When I run the code it returns the message of true but when I look at my list there is no subscriber I found there? Below is my code

```
<cfhttp url="https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/" method="post"  >  

    <cfhttpparam name="output" value="json" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="method" value="listSubscribe" type="URL">
    <cfhttpparam name="apikey" value="3xxxxxxxx1e7a-us5" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="id" value="ccxxxx2b" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="email_address" value="test@hotmail.com" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="merge_vars[fname]" value="test" type="url">

</cfhttp>

<cfset result = JSStringFormat(cfhttp.filecontent)>
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question [was already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728799/mailchimp-api-v1-3-addresses-added-with-listsubscribe-dont-appear-in-dashb/17341209#17341209), but unfortunately with no attention, so I am re-posting it here to give you the solution.

After reading the answer by `@alexleonard` I figured out the problem. The solution to your question is just add an extra   `<cfhttpparam` after the param `fname`:

```
<cfhttpparam name="double_optin" value="FALSE" type="url">
```

Now check it works or not?

Comment: Yes it's work now thanks @arman. I was also worry that why email is not adding to list now by reading the link you have send I clear now the working process of API.